# image url to data URI in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, http, clojurescript

I request an image like this one:
http://img0.ndsstatic.com/wallpapers/da9d3d05e8583820ef7337c3dd49c21c_large.jpeg

and would like to convert the response to proper data URI

I've tried to concat those:
"data:" + respone.headers.content-type + ";base64," + response.body

but it doesn't work.

```
(def data (atom ""))

(go (let [res (a/<! (http/get "http://files.parsetfss.com/42a74b87-d8af-4d8b-9bec-be3039f672fe/tfss-247d838f-26c4-4a0e-89b1-793f5165799b-0.jpg"
                              {:with-credentials? false}))]
      (reset! data
              (str "data:" (get-in res [:headers "content-type"]) ";base64," (js/btoa (:body res))))))
```

Comment: Is `response.body` already base64 encoded? If it's not, try `btoa(response.body)`.

Comment: i've got this: Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: Please share more code. It would be helpful to see *how* you're requesting the image data. Also, is the data being compressed in any way?

Comment: just edit my question, sorry but it is clojurescript

Comment: Can you share the first hundred or so bytes of `(:body res)`?

Comment: "����JFIFHH���ExifMM*\bVnv;~�i�Group of cats and dogs,,Eric Issel√É¬©e�ܠ���\"http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin=\"\" id=\"W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d\"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x=\"adobe:ns:meta/\" x:xmptk=\"XMP Core 5.4.0\"> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"> <rdf:Description rdf:about=\"\"  ...